# Android Animations on button click to display other buttons with fade-in and translate animation programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation

I want to display a buttons with animations like fade-in along with the translate animation programmatically. I have to start translate animation from a specific position on the screen. So i need to pass the x and y values for the translate animation to start from.
Im using the following code for translate animation but how to add fade-in animation to the existing translate animation?

```
TranslateAnimation tanim = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, getIntent().getFloatExtra("ButtonX", maxX),
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, getIntent().getFloatExtra("ButtonY", 0),
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 100);
    tanim.setDuration(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used Animations several times before and they always left me scratching my head. Some things I would recommend you should look into are [Object Animators](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) and [Animator Sets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html). They're really useful, as they allow you to animate any property of the given view. As long as the view has a setter method for that property, you can add it to the animator set by passing in the string name of the property to the Animator constructor. The AnimatorSet class also allows you to easily choreograph multiple animations.

In your case, you could do something roughly like the following:

```
AnimatorSet animations = new AnimatorSet();

Animator xAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationX", finalXValue);
xAnim.setDuration(3000);

Animator yAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationY", finalYValue);
yAnim.setDuration(3000);

Animator alphaAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "alpha", finalAlphaValue);
alphaAnim.setDuration(alphaDuration);

//Play all the animations together
animations.play(xAnim).with(yAnim).with(alphaAnim);
```

You can string together as many animators as you want this way, and you can also set animators to be played in a sequence using the .before() and .after() methods rather than the .with() method.

Comment: that really helped but how can I enter start position of X and Y.. I want the animation to start form a particular point on the screen!

Comment: Use the setTranslationX() and setTranslationY() methods (if you have the coordinates as offsets from the original position) or the setX() and setY() methods (if you have the coordinates as x and y positions) on the button before you start the animation.